# Determine if two separate arguments are true

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Just wondering how to write this if:

```
if ( $(".someDiv").css("pointer-events") != "none" && $elem.hasClass("someClass")) {
  // do something
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to do something if both components of the if are met. Not sure how to use the brackets inside the if, on either side of the **&&**.

Thanks.

Comment: No brackets are necessary -- the `&&` operator has less precedence than `!=`.

Comment: That should do it. What doesn't work???

Comment: Thank you both. It works! Would it help if I said I'm in bed and dreamt about this but wasn't sure? Also, don't know how to mark it as answered.